# Akka context watch/unwatch happens-before relationship

Tags: scala, concurrency, actor, akka, happens-before

I have the following sequential actions on two actors, a *parent* **P** and a *child* **C**:

1. **P** watches **C** (`context watch c`)
2. **P** unwatches **C** (`context unwatch c`)
3. **P** stops **C** gracefully (`c ! PoisonPill`)

What I want to know is; am I guaranteed that **P** *does not receive* a `Terminated` event for **C**?

Here's a sample piece of code

```
class HappensBefore extends App {
  class C extends Actor { def receive = {} } 
  class P extends Actor {
    val c = context actorOf Props[C]
    context watch c
    context unwatch c
    c ! PoisonPill
    def receive = { case Terminated(child) => println("Oh Noes!") }
  }
  ActorSystem("test") actorOf Props[P]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no such guarantee.

Comment: Viktor - thanks for the answer. Is there a way around this? It's critical that in my case actor `P` can deregister itself as a listener from `C` in such a way that, when it subsequently stops `C`, it does not receive a `Terminated` event. Is there some way to attach an `onSuccess` call to the `unwatch` call? Otherwise, what is the use of *unwatching*?

Comment: You do not know if C is terminating from some other reason in between either. Now, it might just work, and do that 100% of the time due to the way it's currently implemented. We just don't guarantee that it will.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit. There is only one call which stops C; that is the one in step 4

Comment: If I stop C directly from the parent, using *context stop c*, would that work?

Comment: No, because the child could have been terminated at some point in time  after the watch was issued.

Comment: I think it'd be more beneficial to resolving your issue if you would outline what the problem is, instead of discussing your solution.